# Как подключить VPN отдельно в браузере

Tags: браузер, vpn

Доброго всем времени суток. Столкнулся с такой проблемой. На работе есть VPN но с закрытым доступом в интернет.
Вопрос можно ли зная учетные данные для авторизации подключить ВПН не на системе а в самом браузере? А имеющиеся в отркытом доступе плагины для впн без спроса подключают к своим серверам.

Comment: Чтобы локалка ВПН-а работала в одном браузере, а в другом был интернет без ВПН

Comment: Что значит учетные данные? Для прокси данные? Если да, то просто поставить расширение любое для работы с прокси - вбить данные и всё.